# Amazon RDS automated hourly snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been looking on Amazon RDS for a way to automatically created incremental snapshots for RDS databases. I want to create hourly snapshots.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use InnoDB as your storage engine. This allows point-in-time restoring with AWS RDS. In order to restore you can just right-click your instance in the Management Console and select "Restore to point in time".